# About file generation when the application is started for the first time

Tags: c#, file, xamarin.forms, file-storage

When the app is started for the first time, folders and files are created, but the app crashes due to an error.
I have file permissions, what should I do?

[AndroidManifest.xml] Permission is set and
At the first startup, the permission confirmation screen is displayed.
After that, [Start.cs] is executed.

```
//AndroidManifest.xml-------------
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionName="1.0.0" package="jp.XXXXXX.XXXX" android:installLocation="preferExternal" android:versionCode="000000">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="29" />
    <application android:label="XXXXXXXX" android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" android:hardwareAccelerated="false" android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" android:largeHeap="true" android:supportsRtl="true" android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" android:icon="@drawable/splash_logo">
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="AIzaSyB34hG3jxWQBog6MMjkaUEK43ZKrtXtWOM" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false" />
        <provider android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
        </provider>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
</manifest>
//-------------

//Start.cs--------------------------
public Start()
{

    try
    {

        private string FolderPath = "XXXXXXXX";

        InitializeComponent();

        if (Directory.Exists(FolderPath) == false)
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(FolderPath);
        }
        
     }
     catch
     {
     
     }
}
//--------------------------
```

Comment: What exception causes the crash?

Comment: The file permission screen is displayed, and even if you press "Allow", an error is displayed as shown below.

[System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to path'/ XXXXXXXXX /'is denied. ]

Comment: you need to prompt the user for access - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/permissions?tabs=android